# Gender detection in R

Tags: r, algorithm, detection

is there a way to do gender detection from a list of European names in R.
Thanks in advance
As example I have this list of names surname couples:

```
namesurname<-c("Hassan Al-Khayr",        "Flores Juberías Carlos" ,"Géza Lévai"  ,           "Miklós Lipták"     ,     "László Péter"    ,       "László Váradi"    ,      "Sándor Molnár"     ,    
  "Csaba Attila Nemes"  ,   "Zoltán Károly"     ,     "István Bajza"      )
```

Comment: The first problem coming to mind is to determine a gender of [Sasha Waltz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasha_Waltz) vs [Sasha Chorny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasha_Chorny).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{genderizeR}` package wraps up calls to genderizer.io's API.
Genderizer.io estimates surnames out of a text string, and correlates them with gender values obtained from vast social media metadata, thus it is quite robust for current naming conventions.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(genderizeR)

namesurname<-c("Hassan Al-Khayr", "Flores Juberías Carlos","Géza Lévai", "Miklós Lipták", "László Péter" ,"László Váradi" , "Sándor Molnár", "Csaba Attila Nemes", "Zoltán Károly", "István Bajza")

df_gender <- findGivenNames(x = namesurname, textPrepare = TRUE)
genderize(x = namesurname, genderDB = df_gender)

                      text givenName gender genderIndicators
 1:        Hassan Al-Khayr    hassan   male                3
 2: Flores Juberías Carlos    carlos   male                2
 3:             Géza Lévai      <NA>   <NA>                0
 4:          Miklós Lipták    miklós   male                1
 5:           László Péter    lászló   male                2
 6:          László Váradi    lászló   male                1
 7:          Sándor Molnár    molnár   male                2
 8:     Csaba Attila Nemes    attila   male                3
 9:          Zoltán Károly    zoltán   male                2
10:           István Bajza    istván   male                2
```